# Merge 2 or more files

Tags: database, bash, merge

i have many db's. All of them contain one table. The name of the table is unknown. What I need is, to put all the tables into one big db.

So if I had 3 files with table1, table2 and table3, i need one file with table1, table2 and table3 in it. The tables itself must not be merged togther, I only need them to be in the same file.

As I dont know how many files with tables I have, I need to do this with bash and parse a list of files.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a very general quesiton, please add details of table structure and required output. Please add what methodologies you have investigated so far and how these haven't worked for you. This question is in it's current form to general for stackoverflow's question policy.

Comment: How would `bash` know the "list of files"? Where/how is it stored?

Comment: OK, here's some more information:

I have a huge perl script, that makes several tests and stores the output for each test in a db-file. The tests have names, e.g. test1 and test2 - so at the end of the test i will have two db-files. The first one will have a table named test1 and the second file will have a table named test2.

The tables have all the same structure (the names of the columns are the same). The problem is, that i don't know these, because the user can change them (or even add another column for the test results).

This is what I tried:

Comment: sqlite3 mergedDB.db <<SQL_ENTRY_TAG_1
CREATE TABLE $darioa (BITRATE, PEAQMETHOD, CODEC, SECTION_NAME, INN, Odg_l, DELAY, NMRB_L, DATE, TIME, LOGFILE );
attach '$1' as toMerge;
insert into param_64 select * from toMerge.param_64;
detach database toMerge;
CREATE TABLE $dariob (BITRATE, PEAQMETHOD, CODEC, SECTION_NAME, INN, Odg_l, DELAY, NMRB_L, DATE, TIME, LOGFILE );
attach '$2' as toMerge;
insert into param_48 select * from toMerge.param_48;
SQL_ENTRY_TAG_1

Comment: But the problem is, that I dont know the column-names. That's why I asked, if there is a general method to combine these files into one file. I think it shouldn't be hard to do, but as I am very new to sql, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the logic of doing it (Might have to modify as per your requirement)

```
while read line
do
count=0
 while read fine
   do
   if [ $count -gt 1 ] #as first line is tablename heading by sql
     then
     mysql -uuser -ppasword -s -e 'CREATE TABLE newdb.$fine  LIKE $line.$fine;'
     mysql -uuser -ppasword -s -e 'INSERT INTO newdb.$fine SELECT * FROM $line.$fine;;'
   done < $(mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -D$line -e 'show databases')
  fi
  count=$(($count+1));

done < $(mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -e `show databases`)
```

This is for all db's

if you keep all db names in a file you can give that filename as input to outer while loop

One to one Copying from mysql prompt is like this

```
 CREATE TABLE db2.table LIKE db1.table;
INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table;
```

Outer while loop gives database names and inner while loop gives table names.

If you keep files with your desired DB names then

```
 while read line
do
count=0
 while read fine
   do
   if [ $count -gt 1 ] #as first line is tablename heading by sql
     then
     mysql -uuser -ppasword -s -e 'CREATE TABLE newdb.$fine  LIKE $line.$fine;'
     mysql -uuser -ppasword -s -e 'INSERT INTO newdb.$fine SELECT * FROM $line.$fine;;'
   done < $(mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -D$line -e 'show databases')
  fi
  count=$(($count+1));

done < dbnames.txt
```

Comment: I could easily generate a list of the db_files. How would I implement this list of files to your script?
It's also some years ago, that I worked with bash, so I might need a little help here too..

Comment: `mysql -uuser -ppassword -s - -e 'show databases' >> dbnames.txt ` and edit file and remove unwanted system database names like information_schema test

Comment: Go for logic & change syntax accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried and I'm getting a syntax error at line 13 because of the "done".

Comment: Yaa I found my mistake.. I corrected it you can now check once

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the *dump* tool of your DB. With sqlite3 something like:

```
sqlite3 mergeDB.sqlite3 < <( sqlite3 db1.sqlite3 <<< ".dump" && sqlite3 db2.sqlite3 <<< ".dump" && sqlite3 db3.sqlite3 <<< ".dump" )
```